# How do I replace the LED bulb in this ceiling light?

Tags: lighting, recessed-lighting

I'm moving out of my flat next week and yesterday (!). This ceiling light went on the blink.

I've managed to get it out of the ceiling but now I'm stuck. It won't come out any further and I've tried turning the silver bezel with no luck, the glass doesn't move either.

Beginning to suspect the entire thing is an 'integrated fixture'. Online research says these things should last 20,000 hours...but the flat is only 5 years old.

Edit: I am in the UK.

2nd Edit: to be clear, I don't want to replace the entire fixture if I can avoid it, just the LED bulb which is housed in the fixture (I am assuming that is what is faulty, it is flickering so I know there is power). Problem is I don't know how to get the bulb out of the housing. The silver bezel doesn't appear to rotate (under reasonable force). There is a pane of glass about 1 inch below the bulb and flush with the bezel which doesn't appear to rotate either. Also, I can't find any switches, latches or knobs on the black part of the housing which will cause the front part to open and let me get at the bulb.

Finally, the top of the black part of the fixture appears to have some sort of protuberances which prevent it from being pulled out of the ceiling. I am baffled as to how they got it through the hole, to be frank.

I was hoping that someone would be familiar with this sort of fixture and could point me to the solution. I am nervous about applying larger amounts of force to try and remove the bezel. I don't want to break anything at this stage given I am moving out next week (and COVID lockdown means it will be difficult to find someone to repair it).

[image: Photo]

Comment: Ask the landlord what it is, it may not be your responsibility to deal with it.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I've asked ... he is an absentee and has never been in the flat :-( No luck there. At the moment I don't see a way of removing/changing this without knocking holes on the ceiling to get it out, so I would definitely try and make it his problem.

Comment: Did  he say if it is a bad fixture that is your responsibility, I would highly doubt that, unless specified by Lease.  Tenets may be responsible for bulbs but not fixtures.

Comment: *should last 20,000 hours...but the flat is only 5 years old.* - 5 years on all the time ~ 40,000 hours; on 1/2 the time ~ 20,000 hours. Plus these sorts of numbers are often MTBF, so even 10,000 would be in the range of "normal failure". In any case, if it is a fixture rather than a removable bulb, that is normally landlord's responsibility.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I understand that, but this is a bathroom light and is probably used about 1 hour per day. Anyway, premature failure does happen. Question is how to change the bulb.

Comment: TBH, it's not really clear from your _question_ that you're looking to replace just the bulb, as opposed to the whole fixture. Usually one doesn't ask about removing the _fixture_ when looking to replace a _bulb_.

Comment: @FreeMan I have edited the question to make it clearer. I was expecting to be able to just change the bulb, but I can't get at it!

Answer (score 4):

How do you change a flat-faced PAR light bulb?  **Do not remove bezels.  Rotate the light bulb by its face**.

How do you grip the *face* of a PAR?  **With a suction cup**.  They make suction cups on sticks for expressly this purpose.  That is why the face of the light bulb is smooth and has all the Fresnel lensing on the inside.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer. The pane of glass which you can see is level with the bezel, extends behind it, and is about an inch below the actual bulb.

Comment: Have you _tried_ it, @PhilipDaniels, or do you just _think_ this isn't the answer?

Comment: @PhilipDaniels If you're saying the bezel you pulled off definitely has a glass pane inset into it, then either that bezel must easily hinge off, or that LED is not replaceable. You may need to get up there on a ladder to *see* how the mechanism works.

Answer (score 4):

Whew, I managed to get it out, by a process of elimination. If you look at the original picture you will see 4 metallic dots at the top right...doing a Google image search for 'LED downlights' implied that this was a spring mechanism to hold some of those expanding wing things. Confirmed by pulling gently down on the fixture - I can feel the springs tensioning. There was no way of getting the whole fixture out, there simply wasn't room to push the springs back.

So I went back to the bezel. I applied a **lot** of force twisting it and managed to turn it back and forth about a quarter turn. It still wouldn't come off, but I could see it flex away from the body a bit....jammed a sharp knife in the gap and managed to lever the entire thing off. Couple of pics to show what the disassembled thing looks like.

[image: Extracted light body]

[image: Body of fixture left in ceiling]

Comment: And I'd just like to say that whoever designed this light is definitely not my friend :-) But I guess they wanted to protect the bulb from bathroom moisture.

Comment: I think it's an IP-rated fitting. Looks almost identical to my IP65 one above the shower